# Getting problem copying one string variable to another string variable in c programming

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, copy, c-strings

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main()
{
    char Word1[10], Word2[10];
    int i;
    
    printf("Enter Text : ");
    scanf("%s", Word1);
    
    for (i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
    {
        Word2[i] = Word1[i];
    }
    
    Word2[i] = '\0';
    printf("The text is : %s\n", Word2);
}
```

So here Im trying to copy 'Word1' to 'Word2' variable but when I print it

```
Enter Text : Harsh
The text is :
```

This is shown(i want the second line to show what's is 'Enter Text : ')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this for loop

```
for (i = 0; i != '\0'; i++)
```

the variable i was initialized by 0.

```
i = 0;
```

So this condition

```
i != '\0';
```

at once is evaluated to logical false.

It seems you mean

```
 for (i = 0; word1[i] != '\0'; i++)
```

You could substitute this code snippet

```
int i;
//...
for (i = 0; word1[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
    Word2[i] = Word1[i];
}

Word2[i] = '\0';
```

for this one

```
for ( size_t i = 0; ( word2[i] = word1[i] ) != '\0'; i++ );
```

or

```
size_t i = 0;
while ( ( word2[i] = word1[i] ) ) i++;
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char word1[] = "Hello World!";
    char word2[sizeof( word1 )];
    
    size_t i = 0;
    while ( ( word2[i] = word1[i] ) ) i++;  
    
    puts( word2 );
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Hello World!
```

Pay attention to that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

Answer (score 1):

condition in "for" loop should be Word1[i] != '\0'